# System cannot find "OfficeStarter.vbs"

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, windows-registry, windows-update

When I boot the computer, I have an error message that reads:

Script:C:\Program Files\WindowsUpdate\OfficeStarter.vbs
Error : The system cannot find the file specified.

I think the problem was that I had installed MS office 2013 preview (maybe pirate) and then return to Office 2010.

For a while I had this error message : "Can't find script engine "VBScript" for script."
, but after fixing this problem by following the advice here 
http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/196011-cscript-error-cant-find-script-engine-vbscript-alternate-solution.htmlv

I have new error message instead.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect the issue is with your Task Scheduler or what is starting with your machine. Use MSCONFIG and check it isn't there.

Option 1) Open Task Scheduler and go through all the folders (if any) looking for the Microsoft ones.

Option 2) Click the start menu and Type `MSCONFIG`. Click the start up tab and remove what you don't want (if you don't know about MSCONFIG, I suggest you read up on it first).